# CDN redirection to subfolder

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I've been struggling with the following problem for the last few days and due to the very nature of a CDN and the manual review of each new rule, it takes me each time up to 4h to deploy a new rule.

I want to redirect abc.domain.com/assets/file1.txt to abc.domain.com/assets/tenant/file1.txt. Both files (assets/file1.txt and assets/tenant/file1.txt) exist.
I tried

[image: CDN configuration]

but for abc.domain.com/assets/file1.txt the assets/file1.txt is opened.

I've seen various posts regarding similar issue but none of the answer seem to cover my case or didn't in the deliver the expected result. The offical documentation(https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/cdn/cdn-verizon-premium-rules-engine-reference-features#url-rewrite) from Microsoft also didn't help in my case.

Comment: I configured URL redirect (please take a look at the screenshot)

Comment: What do you mean `but for abc.domain.com/assets/file1.txt the assets/file1.txt is opened.`, I am not sure what's your issue?